# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable np.where

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new pandas dataFrame column using the numpy.where() function. Can someone tell me why I get the error "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"

The line of code generating the error:
data1['y']=np.where(data1.KINETIC.str.contains("AF"),1,0)

When I execute data1.KINETIC.str.contains("AF") I get the expected result:
0       True
1      False
2       True
3       True
4       True
5      False
...
data1 is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Do you assign to another DataFrame? Or need `data1['data1']=np.where(data1.KINETIC.str.contains("AF"),1,0)` ?

Comment: to a new dataframe, data1['data1] also produce the same error

Comment: hmmm, there should be problem reassign `tuple` like `tuple = 123`, is possible check if not variable called `tuple` ?

Comment: no variable called tuple, I tried reassign tuple but still produce the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need assign to same `DataFrame` called `data1`:

```
data1['data1']=np.where(data1.KINETIC.str.contains("AF"),1,0)
```

Or use alternative with casting `True/False` to `1/0`:

```
data1['data1']=data1.KINETIC.str.contains("AF").astype(int)
```

Comment: The problem don't come from the datframe destination

Comment: thank you, the second solution worked for 1/0 but I need something more general

Comment: @Samir - Is possible restart your IDE?

Comment: Gerat thanks! I restarted the kernel and the problem desappear.